# Which is more correct, "while on the road" or "when on the road"?

Tags: word-choice

If I am going to say a sentence like this:

> Smartphones allow Internet access (?) on the road.

Which conjuctional word should I use in the brackets, "while" or "when"? Are they both acceptable in this sentence? If they are, which one is more prefered by native speakers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question.

IMO, you don't need anything in that sentence though. And, I'm a non-native speaker. Though the question is not asked to us, I'd like to express what I think about the use of 'when' and 'while'. What is preferred by native speakers, they'd only answer.

> Smartphones allow Internet access on the road - seems okay to me!

But then, if it's about putting *while* or *when*...

Both 'when' and 'while' indicate time-related actions. Both the words are quite often used in sentences with past progressive and simple past tenses. In such cases, *while* generally refers to a comparatively long action, on the other hand, *when* could be both a comparatively long or short action. Also, *while* has a clause with *a simultaneous activity* or *ongoing activity*.

> In that sense, both seems okay to me. Smartphones allow Internet access while/when on the road.

Nevertheless, when you are going from one place to another place, your smartphone will get you the Internet access *while* on the road. And, when your friend asks whether smartphones allow access, you may simply nod and say that smartphones allow Internet access *when* on the road.

Comment: If the sentence is going further like: "Smartphones allow Internet access (?) on the road, so people can look up nearby attractions that they don’t want to miss",then which will you choose between "while" and "when"?  I would personally tend to use "while".

Comment: @dennylv I'm a non-native speaker, too, but I think "while" would be better for such expression because the intent is that the internet access is used during the time they are near the attractions. I think "when" would be applicable to single use instance such as looking for help when your car breaks in the middle of nowhere.